# Bernouli principle, input pressure doubles, effect on pressure at narrowing?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

In standard schematic for Bernouli principle, a wide pipe draining into a narrow pipe, if input pressure doubles, is pressure at narrowing larger than or less than when the input pressure not doubled?

Answer (score 0):

When fluid speed increases, pressure decreases.

This is the "Bernoulli effect." But it comes from the Bernoulli principle,

$$P+\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 = \rm{constant.}$$

(I left out the term involving the gravitational potential energy, or the height.)

This is part of the reason aircraft can fly, I think, as well: the air goes over the wings faster than it does under them, so the pressure from above is less than the pressure from below.

Now, when a fluid encounters a narrowing of a pipe, continuity requires that the speed increases: $Av = \rm{constant}$ as well, where $A$ is the cross-sectional area in which fluid flows.

So pressure will decrease at the pipe narrowing.

Comment: What I wondered was, consider a standard Bernouli schematic. The pressure decreases at the narrowing compared to the wider section. Now, double the water pressure input into the system (with a pump. ) Is the pressure at the narrowing then less than or more than it was before (not if it is less than wider section, but less than it was in same narrow section before input pressure was doubled. )

Comment: I see, I didn't understand. I suppose this makes the constant larger, right? If the velocity term is the same for corresponding (wide and narrow) sections of the pipe in both cases, then the pressure should be larger in both cases than without the pump.

Comment: the velocity term would tend to go up though no?

Comment: You've said you increase the pressure. Are you also increasing the velocity?

Comment: well, its a water pipe. it seems to me that if water is pumped in at double the pressure, it must affect the flow rate. i’m just interested in understanding the effect practically.